# Proof that R is uncountable using diagonalization

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I understand that in order to prove that $\Bbb{R}$ is uncountable, one must show that the following list can be compiled:

$$x_{1}=x_{11}x_{12}x_{13}\\x_{2}=x_{21}x_{22}x_{23}\\x_3=x_{31}x_{32}x_{33}\\.\\.\\.$$

But from here I am not sure how one might show that there is some decimal expansion in $(0,1)$ that is not ‘hit’, and so that $f:\Bbb{N}\rightarrow(0,1)$ is not bijective, and so that $\Bbb{R}$ is not countable.

Comment: You need to show the list $cannot$ be compiled. The argument is by contradiction: Assume it is countable, therefore it can be "listed". Now you assume that is an exhaustive list of its elements, and then create a new element not contained in the list. Therefore the list is not exhaustive. Now, since adding that new element to the list does not solve the problem, the original assumption of countability was wrong

Comment: Precisely, @FedePoncio. And you have given a good concise explanation of the proof for OP.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a sequence $y=y_1y_2y_3...$ such that for each $i$, $y_i \neq x_{ii}$.

If $y=x_n$ for an integer $n$, then considering the $n-$th decimal, you would have $y_n=x_{nn}$. This is not true.

So $y$ is not one of the $x_n$.